# smaller images when attaching to MFMailComposer

Tags: ios, uiimage, mfmailcomposer

I have an app that emails a bunch of images. I noticed when I email them to myself, (since there's a lot) my email is very long because mail on the mac automatically previews them. Is there a way to change that so that the email isn't long? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archive them in a .zip, and email the archive containing all the photos. This leaves you with 1 file.

You can look more into Archiving here, http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/